# finding emerging trends in twitter

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

Question here. I realized twitter provide emerging trends globally as well as for individual countries. Is there an easy way for grabbing emerging trends for specific groups of people, say for all my followers and friends? Or am I required to crawl and analyze the data myself?